# Does "Those Who Hunt Elves" have a definitive ending?

Tags: those-who-hunt-elves

I know the manga has ended already, and several years after the 2 seasons of anime which didn't have a definitive ending.

> The second season ended with the attempt to send them back to Japan after all of the spell fragments were collected, but both failed and the fragments were scattered again.

Was there a definitive ending in the manga? Or more specifically:

> Did they get sent back to Japan or was the final attempt the last possible one? Or is it like the ending of the anime where they just have to continue to do it all over and over again?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there where two manga series:

1. *Those Who Hunt Elves* that was adapted almost entirely in the two anime seasons, and
2. *Those Who Hunt Elves Returns*, years after the ending, with new stories not directly continuing but mostly reusing the same characters for new adventures, but was very short.

Finally (for now) in 2013, the author [continued](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-01-15/those-who-hunt-elves-manga-returns-in-new-series) with a new manga, also an "unconnected" continuation, with the same settings and characters but not exactly a sequel since the plots were already closed.

As for the plot that you mention, in the first manga, it was resolved somehow, but keeping the door open for those sequels.